# fetch id and name using postres, create php array with key as id and value as name

Tags: php, database, arrays, postgresql

I am querying my postgres database and getting a name and id like so:

```
$datesQuery = "SELECT date_ridden, id from dates WHERE user_id=$userId"; //query
$theDates = pg_query($db, $datesQuery); //execute query
$dates=array(); //want to use this array to have the key as id and value as date_ridden
```

I want to make my $dates array with the id as the key and date_ridden as the value.

Currently I'm doing the following (which is not what I want to do):

```
while( $date = pg_fetch_row($theDates) ){
        $dates[]['value'] = $date[1]; //date id is value
        $dates[]['label'] = $date[0]; //date (in text form) is the label
}
```

I feel like this should be a really simple thing to do, but for some reason can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the loop structure you are looking for is:

```
while( $date = pg_fetch_row($theDates) ){
    $dates[$date[1]] = $date[0];
}
```

If I misunderstood, then the issue with your current attempt is that it appends the id and label as separate array indexes in `$dates`.

Instead try this:

```
while( $date = pg_fetch_row($theDates) ){
    $dates[] = array('value' => $date[1],
                     'label' => $date[0]);
}
```

With this example, you would access an entry like `Value = $dates[0]['value'], Label = $dates[0]['label']`

Hope one of those helps.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what your asking, then it would be something like this

```
while( $date = pg_fetch_row( $theDates ) ) {
    $dates[][$date[1]] = $date[0];
}
```

or if your wanting to access $dates['some id'] then

```
while( $date = pg_fetch_row( $theDates ) ) {
    $dates[$date[1]] = $date[0];
}
```